Why am I getting the message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
So the first time I ran this code it worked then when I ran it again it came up with the error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
Why is this and how can I fix it?
Here is my code below.
# Import numpy

import numpy as np

# Replace the '?'s with Na in the train and test sets

cc_apps_train = cc_apps_train.replace('?', pd.NA, inplace=True)
cc_apps_test = cc_apps_test.replace('?', pd.NA, inplace=True)

print(cc_apps.tail(17))

I am expecting it to replace

Python is telling you it has an object of type NoneType, and that type doesn't have a .replace method.  So figure why cc_apps_train is set to None.  It looks like cc_apps_train is never getting set before you go to try to call replace on it.

Take another look at the replace documentation.  The documentation of the inplace parameter says
inplace : bool, default False

    If True, performs operation inplace and returns None.

The important point there is that inplace=True implies that the function returns None.  So, assuming that initially cc_apps_train is a DataFrame, this line
cc_apps_train = cc_apps_train.replace('?', pd.NA, inplace=True)

will set cc_apps_train to None.  If you run the same code again, you'll get the error that you reported.  If you are going to use inplace=True, change that line to
cc_apps_train.replace('?', pd.NA, inplace=True)


This would also explain OP's observation So the first time I ran this code it worked then when I ran it again it came up with the error – I assume, OP has the given code as a cell in a Jupyter notebook: (1) The first time the cell is run, cc_apps_* is still an actual DataFrame that has been defined in an earlier cell. (2) On running the cell that contains the code from the question the first time, cc_apps_* is replaced with None for the reason you stated. (3) On running the cell again, the error happens, as cc_apps_* is None now and doesn't have a replace() method, any longer.
